# How do you implement a random number into python

Tags: python, random

so i am making a basic game in python (on a raspberry pi) and for a x coordinate i need it to be random and it wont work when i use random.randint() and therefore i dont know what to do:

as said i need x to be a random number and y to stay as -2

```
def getNewPiece():
    shape = random.choice(list(PIECES.keys()))
    newPiece = {'shape': shape,
                'rotation': random.randint(0, len(PIECES[shape]) - 1),
                'x': random.randint(),
                'y': -2 , 
                'color': random.randint(0, len(COLORS)-1)}
    return newPiece
```

Comment: `random.randint()` always takes 2 arguments; what is the  **range** of values that are allowed for `x`? Just like `rotation` and `color`, the number of values that are *legal* for `x` is not limitless.

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to pass in your range from which the random int needs to be generated.

```
random.randint(1,10)
```

where `1` and `10` are included in the random picking. Therefore, the method above will return any integer between 1 & 10 (inclusive). For a different range, just specify different start and end parameters.

Documentation: **[random.randint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `randrange` ,

Syntax is `random.randrange([start], stop[, step])`

Example ,

```
>>> from random import randrange
>>> print randrange(10)
5
```